# Android: My listView onClick events are not working as intended (order messes up)

Tags: java, android, view, adapter

My program is supposed to show a list of Apps and their data usage. If you click that app, it starts a new activity page and gives more information about that app. Everything works fine on the initial page and all apps show accurate information, but after I scroll down it messes up - the "more info" page shows a different app than the one I clicked.

I'm pretty sure the problem is around the onclick event not being binded to the holder? However I can't figure out what to do there. It should be noted that the problem is fixed if i get rid of the if(convertView == null)/else condition, but I know that is bad practice since we don't want to keep re-generating the previous items

Here is the getView code in my customAdapter:

```
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    final DataUsageModel model;
    model = getItem(position);
    if (convertView == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.customlayout, null);

        convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intentMoreInfo = new Intent(view.getContext(),MoreInfoActivity.class);
                intentMoreInfo.putExtra("wifiUsage",model.getWifiUsage());
                intentMoreInfo.putExtra("mobileUsage",model.getMobileUsage());
                intentMoreInfo.putExtra("appName",model.getName());
                intentMoreInfo.putExtra("pname",model.getPname());

                context.startActivity(intentMoreInfo);


            }
        });
        holder.nameText = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewWord);
        holder.totalUsageText = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewDescription);
        holder.imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.iconImageView);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    holder.nameText.setText(model.getName());

    long usageInMB = (model.getWifiUsage() + model.getMobileUsage())/(1024*1024);
    holder.totalUsageText.setText(String.valueOf(usageInMB) + " MB");

    holder.imageView.setImageDrawable(model.getImageRes());
    return convertView;
}

public class ViewHolder {
    TextView nameText;
    TextView totalUsageText;
    ImageView imageView;
}
```

Here is my code for the new activity started:

```
public class MoreInfoActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView wifiUsage;
    TextView mobileUsage;
    ImageView icon;
    TextView appName;
    Button backButton;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.more_info_layout);

    wifiUsage = findViewById(R.id.moreInfoWifi);
    mobileUsage = findViewById(R.id.moreInfoMobile);
    appName = findViewById(R.id.moreInfoAppName);
    icon = findViewById(R.id.moreInfoIcon);

    backButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.moreInfoBack);
    backButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            finish();
        }
    });

    appName.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("appName"));
    wifiUsage.setText("Wifi Usage: " + String.valueOf(getIntent().getLongExtra("wifiUsage",0)/(1024*1024)) + " MB");
    mobileUsage.setText("Mobile Usage: " + String.valueOf(getIntent().getLongExtra("mobileUsage",0)/(1024*1024)) + " MB");
    try {
        icon.setImageDrawable(getPackageManager().getApplicationIcon(getIntent().getStringExtra("pname")));
    }catch(PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set OnClickListener for every iteration of the getView method, not just when **convertView == null**.

In your case, the current data position is not **synced** with the current view (holder) position for every getView iteration

Furthermore, it is a very bad practice to start the activity from the adapter itself.
The adapter role is to bind view to data, and that's all.

Comment: I see, thanks. Where should i start the "more info" activity then? since the onClick stuff is set up in the adapter

Comment: You can pass an interface from the activity to the adapter, and when onClick happens, invoke some interface method to pass data back to the activity. Another choice is to you the OnItemClickListener of the ListView itself, right from the activity.